# styling issue after removing footer from antd design

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I remove the antd modal footer by `footer={null}` but a empty space stays in.

code:

```
<Modal
  style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", borderRadius: "20px" }}
  width={480}
  footer={null}
>
    <p>
      Done!
    </p>
    <p>
      You've added a name
    </p>
    <Button
      style={{
        borderRadius: "7px",
      }}
    >
      OK
    </Button>
</Modal>
```

Screenshot of the modal:
[image]

I needed to make the modal radius to 20px but after adding the borderRadius, the footer style stays in.

Codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-issue-8x2vm?file=/index.js

Comment: Is the `footer` prop required? Can it just be omitted? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Why do you have closing `</div>` in your code?

Comment: @DrewReese Added a link to codesandbox in the question

Comment: Its happening because of padding.  Try adding class `.ant-modal:{padding-bottom:0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the padding and then also hide the overflow so the border radius is visible.

```
<Modal
  visible={isModalVisible}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    borderRadius: "20px",
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: 0
  }}
  width={480}
  footer={null}
>
  <p>Done</p>
  <p>Added name!</p>
  <Button onClick={handleCancel}>OK</Button>
</Modal>
```

[image]

[image: Edit styling-issue-after-removing-footer-from-antd-design]